# Auto formatting in VIM

Tags: vim, html, formatting

I have a HTML like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Index - feedman</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/bluetrip/css/screen.css" type="text/css" 
media="screen, projection">
[...]
<body>
    <div class="container">
<div id="greeting">
{% if request.user.is_anonymous() %}
<a href="{{ create_login_url() }}">login</a>
{% else %}
Hello {{ request.user }}! <a href="{{ create_logout_url() }}">logout</a>
{% endif %}
</div>

<p>
{{ message }}
</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How should I automatically format with proper indentation using VIM?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you could try : 
**gg=G** to indent all the document ?
I'm not sure it works good with HTML.

Comment: Works for me. ....

Comment: Since I didn't have the file saved, I first had to use :set filetype=html

Comment: Works brilliantly, I didn't know about the `=` command to autoindent. You can use https://github.com/othree/html5.vim to add support for HTML5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) as explained in the [vim tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanup_your_HTML):

> exe 'setlocal equalprg=tidy -quiet -f '.&errorfile
>
> setlocal makeprg=tidy -quiet -e %

Comment: No tidy please; I wonder if VIM supports this feature at all (that Emacs already has)